# replace numpy array loop in array calculations

Tags: arrays, loops, numpy

Hi is there a faster and easy option to do below code without using loop? When increasing multiplier value the computation is time expensive.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import timeit

multiplier = 2
vectors_number = 4 * multiplier
variable_number = 6
input_matrix = np.random.uniform(-5, 5, (vectors_number, variable_number))

offset = np.arange(multiplier)[:, None]*4
winning_matrix = np.random.rand(multiplier, 4).argsort(1)[:, :4] + offset

out_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(multiplier, variable_number))
start = timeit.default_timer()

for i in range(winning_matrix.shape[0]):
    for k in range(variable_number):
        out_matrix[i][k] = input_matrix[winning_matrix[i][2]][k] - 
                           input_matrix[winning_matrix[i][1]][k]

end = timeit.default_timer()
print('Computation time %f' % (end - start))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
out_matrix = input_matrix[winning_matrix[...,2]] - input_matrix[winning_matrix[...,1]]
```

Using

```
multiplier = 200
vectors_number = 4 * multiplier
variable_number = 6000
```

I get

> Computation time 1.576242

for the original method, and

> Computation time 0.027881

for my code above. So a speed up of about 140.

Note that you can also get rid of the allocation & initialisation step:

```
out_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(multiplier, variable_number))
```

since `out_matrix` is now created for you.